# Django tags in filter output - how to evaluate

Tags: django

So can a filter output  django tags that get evaluated in the current context.  Maybe there's a way to do this with inclusion tags, but a filter where python just formats a Django string with variables you supply seems more straightforward,  but thus far the Django tags are just output by the filter unevaluated.

clarification:

so  the filter outputs "{% counter %}" into the page text, instead of the calculated value of counter.  How do I direct Django to evaluate the output of this filter as Django in the current context, iow "unescape" the Django content

Comment: Hey Mark - just a hint not to answer your own question unless you're actually solving it (because people look at unanswered questions more than answered ones). Just modify your question instead :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, maybe the `include` tag will solve this, as I can use parameters with it...